# Unity - UWP: How to import dll/nuget-package/references to my project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, kinemic

**Context**
I got this [uwp demo project](https://github.com/kinemic/kinemic-quickstart-uwp-app) which uses this [sdk](https://kinemic.com/en/developerarea/installation/?opanda_confirm=1&opanda_lead=35&opanda_code=2b172d4377cfcb1daaad9978d9b45faf). The sdk is available for Windows UWP C#. Running its solution works fine and it does what it's supposed to do. Now I want to use it in my unity project, which is set up for the ar glasses HoloLens (choosed uwp as bulding platform in unity).
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 **Question**
How can I use the dll from the demo project in my unity project?

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**What I tried**
1. I took the dlls out of the build dir of the demo project and imported them to unity. I created  a folder `Assets\Plugins` and put it there. Trying to use it via `using Kinemic.Gesture` gives me the error `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Kinemic' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` I also tried to add the reference by using the reference manager and taking the dll from the pluing folder, but then I got this notification: 
[image]


2. I took the nuget-package and changed the format to .zip, so I can unzip it and take the dlls out of it. But I got only targets:
[image]
3. I opened my unity project in visual studio by opening a script in unity. Created by `right click on solution → Add new project → Class Library (Universal Windows)` a new project. That way I could add the package via nuget manager:
[image]
 I thought building this project should give me the dlls/references but all I get is this error in Unity:
[image]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**My setup**
Unity 2019.2.9f1
Visual Studio Pro 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only correct way of adding external DLLs to unity in the listed trials above is the first one, every other method will not compile/build or crash at runtime (guaranteed).

So how to use a UWP library in unity.

### For a C# library

If it says Type: 'Managed' and Targets some .NET x.y, then it is.

[image]

- **1-1:** In previous screenshot, if the library 'Targets .NET 4.x then edit your project settings to target .NET 4.x [image]
- **1-2:** Again, in the first screenshot, select the library, and edit the 'Include Platforms' with **only** *UWP (WSA Player)* platform selected, any other platform won't work including the editor.
- **1-3:** Build your project, without trying to use the library:

  - Did it build safely ? great, proceed to next step.
  - Did it produce errors ? figure out what the reason was and why.
- **1-4:** Since this is a UWP library, and there is no unity editor version for it, you won't get intellesense support for it, and so  `using Kinemic.Gesture` will produce errors in the editor, any code in that library needs to be wrapped inside `#if` directive for UWP platform.

  - An `#if` directive simply tells unity to ignore that code until the app is running at build on specific platform, since only then will the library be usable by unity, to learn more: [Platform dependent compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)

    For example:

> ```
> #if UNITY_WSA
> using Kinemic.Gesture;
> #endif
> using UnityEngine
>
> public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour
> {
>     public void SomeFunction
>     {
>         #if UNITY_WSA
>         // call some code in the Kinemic.Gesture library.
>         #endif
>     }
>
> }
> ```

### For a Native Library

It is a little bit trickier than that, but you get all intellesense support, it would still be only functional in the build tho.

One way is to interop with the library from your unity scripts using PInvoke, for more information see Unity [Nativ Plug-ins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html)

Another way, which I like is to write a wrapper C# library for this C++ library and import the C# wrapper to unity, this is achieved by:

- Create a Class Library (.NET Framework) C# project.
- Import Kinemic from nuget or by adding reference.
- Start with a class called UnitKinemicWrapper, that looks like:

  ```
  using Kinemic.Gesture;
  public class UnityKinemicWrapper
  {
   public static void KinemicConnect(string band)
   {
       Kinemic.Gesture.Engine.Connect(band);
   }
  }
  ```

  - Build your C# wrapper library, and import it to unity.
  - Configure it with the steps at the very beginning of this guide for configuring C# libraries, in addition to that, tell unity to not process this library by un-ticking these checkboxes, then hit apply.

[image]

- Now in your unity scripts you can call

  ```
    string band = "band";
    UnityKinemicWrapper.KinemicConnect(band);
  ```

### Another approach for UWP projects only

Don't import any Kinemic libraries to unity.

- Build your unity project.
- Open the UWP produced project.
- From there, contact unity using UnityEngine.GameObject.SendMessage, more about [SendMessage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html)

Comment: Thanks for your guide! I followed your steps and thats what I got.(1) Clicking on my dll it says [`Type = Native`](https://imgur.com/KVb4Ild) and not like in your screenshot `managed`? (2) I went until step 3 and the build was successful, had no error and when open the buildet project I saw the [Kinemic.Gesture.dll referenced](https://imgur.com/eglgfML). (3) If I use then `#if directives` and try to build, the build failes with `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Kinemic' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

Comment: This is how the [demo uwp project and the output folder](https://imgur.com/J4Lefxd) looks like. I take only the `Kinemic.Gesture.dll` out of the build folder and put it in unity. Maybe I'm doing here something wrong? But I guess the problem is that the dll is `unmanaged → native`?

Comment: You can check modified answer, I added details for handling Native libraries, hope that sets you on the right path.